# Streaming data using Spring Data JPA to excel file download as chunks java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, stream, apache-poi

We are trying to stream million number of DB records from postgraes sql using JPA stream, and download as excel (using Apache poi to create excel, other library also fine).

similar solution like csv: https://www.geekyhacker.com/2019/03/26/high-performance-data-fetching-using-spring-data-jpa-stream/

Example snippet:

BookRepository class:

```
 @QueryHints(value = {
     @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "10000")
 })
 @Query("select b from Book")
 Stream<Book> getAll();
```

Controller:

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public void processBooks() {
  Stream<Book> bookStream = bookRepository.getAll();
  OutputStream  outputStream  = response.getOutputStream();
  bookStream.forEach(book -> {
  //Excel file rows and workbook creation and streaming here
  workbook.write(outputStream);//getting stream closed error
 });
}
```

Comment: The max number of rows in Excel will be 1,048,576, and you will have to load all to create the Workbook. So streaming will not help much

Comment: max number of rows per sheet will be 1,048,576, we will create multiple sheets

Comment: As you appear to have an [_XY problem_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/163188), please [edit] your question to reframe it; more [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-exceed-excels-limits-number-of-rows/783984c2-5ab4-41c8-8e7e-948d7bf58edc).

Comment: There is not any well working streaming approach to write Excel files because of the complex internal structure of all kinds of Excel files. There are partially working tries, `SXSSF` for example. But even this is not really a full streaming approach.

Comment: why do you need excel format? Excel is not a good data interchange format - it is a proprietary Microsoft solution and the file format has numerous weaknesses - exchanging large data is better done with formats like CSV, JSON, Parquet, etc.

Comment: we are using csv, want to give option for excel download as well

Comment: Users likely complained they couldn't open such enormous `.csv` files. As an alternative, consider offering users an archive of segments that Excel _can_ use.